# Forgot password/other member functions busted

Tags: members, login, forgot-password

I've taken over a site that has a lot of customization.

URLs like: /member/forgot_password yield a blank page. If I visit them when logged in as a superadmin, I get this debugging info:

```
(0.000004 / 11.29MB) - Begin Template Processing -
(0.000398 / 11.36MB) URI: member/forgot_password
(0.000408 / 11.36MB) Path.php Template: /
(0.000415 / 11.36MB) Retrieving Template
(0.000420 / 11.36MB) Parsing Template URI
(0.002118 / 11.68MB) Template group and template not found, showing 404 page
(0.002130 / 11.68MB) Retrieving Template from Database: /
(0.003083 / 11.69MB) Template Not Found
(0.003096 / 11.69MB) Template Type: 404
```

Detective work to figure out just what would hide this basic member function. Member login does work, sort of.

Comment: Is the Member module installed?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Client had set the profile trigger to '---jkhadhaksdhvasdv'.time()

Which randomizes it. Great for avoiding member spam, awful for making member profile functions work!

Thanks all.

Answer (score 1):

Make sure the member profile trigger word is set in the control panel member preferences. That word `example.com/member/profile/` is used to 'trigger' the member module

http://ellislab.com/expressionengine/user-guide/cp/members/membership_preferences.html

**edit**: that being said: i generally use the Free_member add-on, which allows templating these member forms and removes the default oldschool 3 second "you are now logged in" 3 second redirect delay screen.

Comment: Indeed, the member module is installed. There is a profile triggering word, it is a gibberish string intended to prevent membership spam. When I go to /gibberish/forgot_password or /gibberish/profile I get the same results.

Comment: This might not be easy to resolve with a quick answer. I'ld definitely try free_member? it also allows you to more easily style the member forms.

Comment: What does your debug info look like when you access the gibberish/profile/ url?  Is it the same or are the errors different?